# Lumen (Laravel): Partial JSON response returned while fetching large data using Eloquent

Tags: php, json, laravel, eloquent, lumen

I am getting partial JSON response while retrieving data (approx. 3MB JSON) from database using Laravel Eloquent.

But when I am retrieving the same data using normal php database connection, it works fine.

I have already set memory_limit in my php.ini file to handle large data.

Is there anything I need to set in my Laravel (Lumen) database configuration?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem a few days back while working with the **lumen** framework.
To solve this you need to add

this line --> `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_MAX_BUFFER_SIZE => 20000000` ,

here --> `/vendor/illuminate/database/Connectors/Connector.php` in the `options array` (line 12).

The default value for `MYSQL_ATTR_MAX_BUFFER_SIZE` is set to **1MB** and hence your result is being truncated.

thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

You can chunk it up:

```
$results = collect();

Model::where('foo', 'bar')->chunk(function ($models) use ($results) {
    $results->merge($models->toArray());
});

return $results;
```